# Binomial equation

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I need to prove the following equation:

$\sum_{j=k}^n \binom{j}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$

for this equation i need to suggest both algebric and combinatorial explanation.

the only thing I came up with:

as for the right side, combinatorial explanation could be number of ways for choosing subsets of k+1 people out of a n+1 people in total.

left side, though, doesnt work out for me at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k}=?$$

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. managed to deal with the combinatorial explanation. I need to proove this using algebra only. any suggestion?

Comment: especially left side doesnt work well for me.

Comment: Jmoravitz I am pleased with what you wrote, If you wish to rewrite it so I can accept the answer that will be great.